# How does this Scapy DHCP DoS/Exhaustion attack work?

Tags: python, scapy, dhcp, denial-of-service

I came across this *DHCP* Exhaustion/DoS `Scapy` script.  It works by making multiple *DHCP* Discovery packets from different MAC addresses in order to use all of the available IP addresses on the *DHCP* server.

From my knowledge, a device sends a *DHCP* discovery packet in order to get an IP address then the *DHCP* server sends a offer packet, the client sends a *DHCP* request and then finally the *DHCP* server sends a final packet saying that the device is allowed to use the IP address.

HOWEVER, in this script it only sends a *DHCP* discovery packet. How does this script work if the client also needs to send a *DHCP* request back to the *DHCP* server in order for the *DHCP* server to send a packet back that 'finalizes' the IP address allocation.

```
from scapy.all import *

dhcp_discover = Ether(dst='ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff',src=RandMAC())  \
                     /IP(src='0.0.0.0',dst='255.255.255.255') \
                     /UDP(sport=68,dport=67) \
                     /BOOTP(op=1,chaddr = RandMAC()) \
                     /DHCP(options=[('message-type','discover'),('end')])

sendp(dhcp_discover,iface='eth0',loop=1,verbose=1)
```

My only guess is that when I run the script, my computer's kernel handles the *DHCP* request packet and thus, finalizes the allocation. Is this correct??